# Why is my submit button not working in conjunction with UPDATE statement?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, submit

I have two forms on one page. One is to delete the users account, the other is to `UPDATE` the users details (the users 'diet' to be precise). The forms use different `values` for their submit buttons as they are two seperete forms where the user only chooses one to fill in and not both.

I am trying to get the submit button of my UPDATE statement to work but nothing happens when you press the button. The UPDATE statement is to update the users ' dietID ' in the ' users ' table stored on my MySQL database. I'm fairly new to php, I would appreciate any help!

Form processing code for update diet for the logged in user:

```
<?php 
$sess_userID =$_SESSION['userID'];
$dietopt = trim($_POST['dietopt']);
if(trim($_POST['submit']) == "Change") {
        if (trim($_POST['dietopt']) == 1) {
            require_once("connect.php");
            if (!$db_server) {
                die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error($db_server));
            } else {
                mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database) or die("<h1>Couldn't find db</h1>");
                //UPDATE records of users table
                $query="UPDATE users SET option= .$option . WHERE ID= $dietopt";
                mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or die("Update failed" . mysqli_error($db_server));   
                header('location: account.php');
            }
            require_once("db_close.php");
        } else {
            //do nothing
        }
}
```

HTML form:

```
Would you like to change what your current diet is? Please select one
<br>
<td><input type="radio" name="dietopt" value="Meat-eater"/>Meat-eater</td>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="dietopt" value="Vegetarian"/>Vegetarian</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="dietopt" value="Vegan"/>Vegan</td></tr>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="Change" value="Change">
```

On my register page I have the following variables created:

```
$dietopt=trim($_POST['dietopt']);
$_SESSION['diet'] = $diet;
```

And the the WORKING code for my delete form is:

```
<?php
$sess_userID = $_SESSION['userID'];
if (trim($_POST['submit']) == 'submit') {
    if (trim($_POST['delete']) == 1) {
        require_once("connect.php");
        if (!$db_server) {
            die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error($db_server));
        } else {
            mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database) or die("<h1>Couldn't find db</h1>");
            //DELETE records from comments table
            $query = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE userID=$sess_userID";
            mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or die("Delete 1 failed" . mysqli_error($db_server));
            //DELETE record from users table
            $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE ID=$sess_userID";
            mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or die("Delete 2 failed" . mysqli_error($db_server));
            //LOGOUT AND DESTROY SESSION
            $_SESSION = array();
            session_destroy();
            header('Location: index.php');
        }
        require_once("db_close.php");
    } else {
        header('location: home.php');
    }
}
```

With form:

```
<h3><p> Are you sure you want to delete your entire account <?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>?</p> 
This will remove your username, password and any comments or photos you have uploaded to our Community forum. We promise to delete all of your details and we will not store or sell your information.</h3>
 <form action="account.php" method="post">
 Yes:<input type="radio" name="delete" value="1" /><br />
 No: <input type="radio" name="delete" value="0" checked="checked" /><br />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
 </form>
```

Comment: Wrong condition  `$_POST['submit']) == "Change")` because your field name is `name="Change"`

Comment: Also wrong  in syntax update query `query="UPDATE users SET option= .$option . WHERE ID= $dietopt";
`

Comment: Another remark is : `if (trim($_POST['dietopt']) == 1) {` it's never going to be 1..

Comment: is your submit button is in `<form>` tag??

Comment: @saty ok so do I change it to $_POST['change']) ? I thought the == meant it knew which submit button to use. And what syntax have I done wrong in my update query? I am new to this, apologies.

Comment: @AjayMakwana oh wow how did I forget to add form tags. Thank you very much for pointing out my idiotic mistake!

Comment: @Naruto but it works for my delete form? Which uses radio buttons to submit

Comment: Use `if(isset($_POST['Change'])){...`

Comment: @Saty thank you. However it has not changed anything

Comment: echo your update query and post it here

Comment: @saty Sorry to sound dumb but I do not know how to echo my query exactly

Answer (score 1):

It is because you don't have form element in your html code
Your Form

```
Would you like to change what your current diet is? Please select one
<br>
<form action="your-action-page.php" method="post">
<td><input type="radio" name="dietopt" value="Meat-eater"/>Meat-eater</td>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="dietopt" value="Vegetarian"/>Vegetarian</td>
</tr>          
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="dietopt" value="Vegan"/>Vegan</td></tr>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="Change" value="Change">
</form>
```

Processing Page

```
<?php 
$sess_userID =$_SESSION['userID'];
$dietopt = trim($_POST['dietopt']);
if(trim($_POST['submit']) == "Change") {
    if ($_POST['dietopt'] == 1) {
        require_once("connect.php");
        if (!$db_server) {
            die("Unable to connect to MySQL:".mysqli_connect_error($db_server));
        } else {
            mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database) or die("<h1>Couldn't find db</h1>");
            //UPDATE records of users table
            $query="UPDATE users SET option='".$option."' WHERE ID= ".$sess_userID;
            mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or die("Update failed" . mysqli_error($db_server));   
            header('location: account.php');
        }
        require_once("db_close.php");
    } else {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I added this but it has not updated anything in the mysql database.

Comment: change WHERE ID= ".$dietopt; to WHERE ID =".$sess_userID; in your query

Comment: Nope that didn't work either. I appreciate you helping me

Comment: can you echo your query and post here
just type echo $query;die(); after $query="UPDATE users SET option='".$option."' WHERE ID= ".$sess_userID;

Comment: ok this appears: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/me14ch/public_html/chefsclaw/account.php on line 77

Comment: I think you placed echo before the query link your code should look like this
$query="UPDATE users SET option='".$option."' WHERE ID= ".$sess_userID; echo $query;die();

Comment: oops! thank you. Ok I did that and no errors have appeared on my page, and the update is still not working

Comment: I think I figured out the problem. Now on third line change code to $dietopt = trim($_POST['dietopt']); echo $dietopt; die(); and post me the result.

Comment: doing that removed the entire form from the page and now no longer shows on my page

Comment: I meant on the processing page

Comment: I have edited the code of processing page use it. And if you still have issue echo your query as mentioned above. Post the results

Comment: Used the processing page - no submission/update worked. Echo'd the query, entire form disappears from the page again :( I appreciate your help and patience